# iterating loops and subs for n number of lists in list

Tags: python, regex, replace, iterator, zip

I hope this is as less confusing as it looks. I have a problem where I am trying to replace n number of words within sentences, iterating through all the combinations based on their parts-of-speech.
i.e.

- make a image
- make a site
- make a stock
- get a image
- get a site
- get a stock...

I am new to using iterables and automating this loop based on n number of words to replace has me scratching my head. The following below is sample data...

```
> replaceable_list: [('mow', 'VB'), ('lawn', 'NN')]

> mostCommon_list [['make', 'get', 'draw', 'sign', 'sell'], ['image', 'site', 'stock', 'drawing', 'photo', 'way', 'people', 'money', 'image', 'skill']]

> Question: "You are trying to earn one hundred nine dollars for some new CDs. If you charge forty-seven dollars to mow a lawn, how many lawns will you need to mow to earn the money?"
```

As you can see, I already have the mostCommon_list corresponding to the replaceable_list. The last code I've been using is as follows:

:)

```
question = word_tokenize(question)
first_word = question
#This loops through each replacement word
mostCommonwords, mostCommonPOS = zip(*replaceable_list)
commonlisttuples = list(itertools.product(*mostCommon_list))
for wordsintuple in commonlisttuples:
    for wordintuple in wordsintuple:
        #print(wordintuple)
        for commonwords in mostCommonwords:
            print(replace_all(str(question), commonwords, wordintuple))
```

**I'm sooo close! Update: I have change the above code to:**

```
    for x in result:
    print("x", x)
    for idxy, val in enumerate(replaceable_list): #Caputure the word and the POS in list
    #print("idxy", idxy, "\n", "val", val, "\n")
        print("replaceable_list",val[0]) #prints each replacement word
        print("mostCommon_list[idxy]",mostCommon_list[idxy], "\n") #prints the list that the replacement should come from 
        print(replace_all(str(first_word), val[0], x[idxy])) #target, find, replacement
```

Here is the replace_all function I forgot to mention. My apologies..

```
  def replace_all (target,find,replace):
  return replace.join(target.split(find))
```

Now, I'm trying to add the returned results together. The input is **mow a lawn** but the output looks like:

- **make** a lawn
- mow a **image**
- **make** a lawn
- mow a **site**
- **make** a lawn
- mow a **stock**

Instead of..

- **make** a **image**
- **make** a **site**
- **make** a **stock**
- **get** a **image**
- **get** a **site**
- **get** a **stock**...

Comment: not sure if I got your question clearly enough, but won't just knowing the index in `replaceable_list` suffice? So, instead of for loop, try using `for idx, val in enumerate(replaceable_list)` and then use corresponding idx value for replacement from `mostCommon_list`

Comment: Thanks @siberiancrane. Im not understanding how what you describe will not use several for loops (i.e looping through the "verb items") but I am trying it out.

Comment: Your question mentions a lot of things but doesn't succinctly mention the problem you are facing. If the problem is trying to iterate through multiple lists, without writing multiple for loops, you can consider using `itertools.izip()`, which basically iterates with the values `izip('ABC', 'abcd', '12345') -> Aa1 Bb2 Cc3` (or its sibling izip_longest(), which has an extra fillervalue argument)

Comment: @siberiancrane I have added my updated code and my problem with more detail. I hope it makes sense. I've tried using zip but I had a problem using it without knowing the number of tuples necessary.

Comment: @siberiancrane I got it working the same day. Thanks for your last suggestion. It helped!